# Using VLOOKUP with an additional VLOOKUP on FALSE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am trying to use `vlookup` in Google Sheets to populate my price data in my inventory database called "Food Inventory".  The data I am looking to match is the "description" which is the A column in all three sheets.

I have a price data sheet with a named range `pricedata` and an Old Price Data sheet with a named range `oldprice`.

I would like to find the most current price data and if there is no match look in the Old price data sheet.

Here is the formula I am using which is not working:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,PriceData,4,0),VLOOKUP(A3,oldprice,4,0)
```

I would prefer not to use array formulas, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there but one can't link two VLOOKUPs with just a `,` in the way you attempted. If the first attempt (in `PriceData`) fails an error will be returned. This can be used to trigger the second attempt with IFERROR:

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(A3,PriceData,4,0),VLOOKUP(A3,oldprice,4,0))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I feel so foolish for not thinking of that!  Thanks so much for your help.